# Subset Sum Problem: Returning the indices of the values instead of the values

Tags: python

would like to know how to put a twist on the subset sum problem.

Given a list of integers and a target integer, I want to compute all the possible groups (consisting of **2 or 3 members**) from the list that sum up to the target.

The output will be a 2D list of groups with the **indices of the 2 or 3 numbers**.

So for example,

nums = [3, 0, 1, 0, -1, -2, 0]

t = 0

ttsum(nums, t) returns [[1, 3], [1, 6], [2, 4], [3, 6], [0, 4, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6]]

Thank you!!!

Comment: What all have you tried? Can you post your code here?

Answer (score 1):

Also find the combinations of a list that represents the indices. Check the sum, then take the indices.

```
from itertools import combinations
l = [3, 0, 1, 0, -1, -2, 0]

[list(idx) for i in range(2, 4, 1) for seq,idx in zip(combinations(l, i), combinations(range(0, len(l), 1), i)) if sum(seq) == 0]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3],
 [1, 6],
 [2, 4],
 [3, 6],
 [0, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 3, 6],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [2, 4, 6]]
```